# Dynamic link won't trigger bootstrap modal - Joomla

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, modal-dialog

My first post here, so don't be too harsh!

I've been struggling with this for hours, and I can't figure it out.  I have the following in a custom html module in Joomla 3.3.6:

`<div id="modalLink"></div>`

I'm updating the div contents with this variable from an external js file:

`var modalTarget = "<a id='launchModal' class='modal' href='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=34&tmpl=component' >Launch Modal</a>";`

I've tried using both `jQuery(modalTarget).appendTo("#modalLink")` and `jQuery("#modalLink").html(modalTarget)`.

If I hard code the exact same link it launches the URL in a modal.  But when I generate it with jQuery it just hard loads the page.

If I check the class of the anchor after it's created with `jQuery('#launchModal').attr('class')` it shows that it has the "modal" class.  It just doesn't work!

I suspect that even though the class has been applied, the css associated with the class isn't loaded. I just can't figure out how to fix it.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: you need to bind the modal plugin again because you updated the dom

Comment: post your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Hi madalin thanks for the tip I'll look into it. I've already looked at .on and .delegate for a solution but I couldn't see a way of implementing what I need.  All I really want is to have the link initialised and ready for a click event.